# Merge the cell values if duplicates exist

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to merge the values in column B if Duplicates exist in Column A

```
   A    B
  123   A
  123   B
  123   C
  456   D
  456   E
  789   F
```

My output should look like this

```
  A     B
 123    A B C
 456    D E
 789    F
```

I have a large amount of data and it is hard to do it manually ,So u guys have any idea to do it in macros in Excel?

Any help will be appreciated..Thanks in Advance

Comment: looping + concatenating ...

Comment: Thank u i will try with your hint but iam new to macros..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the resultant data in the same cells the original data existed ie not in Cell 10, then you have to store the source data in a two dimensional array. Then from the array we have use the above code to insert the data in the same place the original data existed. Here goes the listing to accomplish the task:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim names(2 To 7, 2)
For i = 2 To 7
names(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
names(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2)
Next
On Error Resume Next:
Sheet1.Cells.Clear
 cnt = 2
    For i = 2 To 7
    strg = strg + names(i, 2)
    If names(i + 1, 1) <> names(i, 1) Then
    Cells(cnt, 1) = names(i, 1)
    Cells(cnt, 2) = strg
    cnt = cnt + 1
    strg = ""
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Please note that I have declared names array with two dimesnions to store the data. Then the array is searched to get the result.

Comment: Thank u so much @Rangan U made my hours of work in to minutes.. i need a space between the concatenated values.

Comment: Yes i got a space between the values by adding strg=strg+" "+names(i,2).. Thank u so much,It works perfect now..

Answer (score 3):

I'd cheat, and use formulas as follows;
1) Sort by column A

2) In col C, add a formula to test if the current one is last (assuming there's a header, put this in C2

```
=if(A2<>A3,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Now, this should only be true for the last cell in a series of same ID's

3) in Col D, add a formula for concatenating if the ID's are the same,

```
=if(A2=A1,D1&" "&B2,B2)
```

4) Filter on column C to show only the last cell in each series.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry When i try this i got my output as 0CDEF0 in column D which was not my expected output,Do u have any idea?Any way thank u for your help..

Comment: I have no idea how you end up with a hex code.....Check that you have a header row, and that your formula's begin at row 2.

Comment: Im sorry Rowan Its working Thank u..+1 ,Now i want to remove the duplicate cells in Column A except the last resultant cell,How to do that Any Guess?

Comment: copy all of your data, and paste it in place as values. Then Reverse the filter (on column C, selecting only falses), select all of the rows & delete the rows. You should be left only with the summary. Alternately, filter column C by true, and copy the results onto a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    cnt = 10
    For i = 2 To 7
    strg = strg + Cells(i, 2)
    If Cells(i + 1, 1) <> Cells(i, 1) Then
    Cells(cnt, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(cnt, 2) = strg
    cnt = cnt + 1
    strg = ""
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The requested data will be printed from Cells 10

Comment: Thank u @Rangan Its working +1 ,i want to add some space between the concatenated values i tried strg=" ",but not working.

Comment: @Rangan: Instead of posting answers as different users, can you delete this answer and merge it with the above answer? If not, delete this answer please.